# zip dict converts a integer list to a string while creating a JSON file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to save a `JSON` file from a dataframe.

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

df

    Metric          Value
0   Line1           10% off
1   Line2           15% off
2   Line3           20% off
3   Line4           25% off
4   Line5           30% off
5   revenueXaxis    ['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5', 'Week 6', 'Week 7', 'Week 8']
6   Revenuedata1    [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]
7   Revenuedata2    [25, 25, 25, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25]
8   Revenuedata3    [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]
9   Revenuedata4    [15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
10  Revenuedata5    [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

When I perform below `zip` operation to convert it as a dictionary, the list values in `Revenuedata1` to `Revenuedata5` is converted into a string as below:

```
dict(zip(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1]))

{'Line1': '10% off',
 'Line2': '15% off',
 'Line3': '20% off',
 'Line4': '25% off',
 'Line5': '30% off',
 'revenueXaxis': "['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5', 'Week 6', 'Week 7', 'Week 8']",
 'Revenuedata1': '[30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]',
 'Revenuedata2': '[25, 25, 25, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25]',
 'Revenuedata3': '[15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]',
 'Revenuedata4': '[15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]',
 'Revenuedata5': '[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]'}
```

And when I write it to a file using `json.dump`, this is the output I get:

```
 "ExpectedRevenue": {
        "Line1": "10% off",
        "Line2": "15% off",
        "Line3": "20% off",
        "Line4": "25% off",
        "Line5": "30% off",
        "revenueXaxis": "['Week 1', 'Week 2', 'Week 3', 'Week 4', 'Week 5', 'Week 6', 'Week 7', 'Week 8']",
        "Revenuedata1": "[50, 110, 180, 260, 350, 450, 550, 650]",
        "Revenuedata2": "[20, 45, 75, 110, 150, 195, 245, 300]",
        "Revenuedata3": "[5, 15, 28, 43, 60, 78, 98, 120]",
        "Revenuedata4": "[4, 10, 17, 2, 35, 46, 58, 72]",
        "Revenuedata5": "[3, 8, 13.5, 19.5, 26.5, 34.5, 44, 54]"
    },
```

Could someone please let me know how to keep the integer list values as is and not a string.

Expected Output:

```
"ExpectedRevenue": [{
    "Line1": "10% off",
    "Line2": "15% off",
    "Line3": "20% off",
    "Line4": "25% off",
    "Line5": "30% off",
    "revenueXaxis": ["Week 1", "Week 2", "Week 3", "Week 4", "Week 5", "Week 6", "Week 7", "Week 8"],
    "Revenuedata1": [50, 110, 180, 260, 350, 450, 550, 650],
    "Revenuedata2": [20, 45, 75, 110, 150, 195, 245, 300],
    "Revenuedata3": [5, 15, 28, 43, 60, 78, 98, 120],
    "Revenuedata4": [4, 10, 17, 2, 35, 46, 58, 72],
    "Revenuedata5": [3, 8, 13.5, 19.5, 26.5, 34.5, 44, 54]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If string starting by `[` convert values to lists by [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) only for filtered rows:

```
import ast

m = df['Value'].str.startswith('[')
df.loc[m, 'Value'] = df.loc[m, 'Value'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Last create dictionary:

```
print (df.set_index('Metric')['Value'].to_dict())

print (dict(zip(df.iloc[:,0], df.iloc[:,1])))
```

EDIT: You can check not converted values and repalce them by empty list, also use `print` for see what values failed:

```
import ast

def literal_eval_cust(x):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(x)
    except Exception:
        print (x)
        return []
    

df.loc[m, 'Value'] = df.loc[m, 'Value'].apply(literal_eval_cust)
```

Comment: Running into this error `ValueError: malformed node or string` on another such column in `ast.literal_eval` step, Could you please let me know if I need to check anything? Strange because it ran fine when I executed same code on same, but now it's throwing that error

Comment: @KarthikS - Sure, give me a sec.

Comment: @KarthikS - Answer was edited.

Comment: I used `astype(str)` on the column, it ran without error, I checked the values, none of them were python literals, not sure what the issue was. The entire column was in the form of `dictionary` enclosed in the `list`

Comment: Just a followup query Jezrael, I have many such dicts, `Engagement = dict(zip(Engagement.iloc[:,0], Engagement.iloc[:,1])),
NoResponse = dict(zip(NoResponse.iloc[:,0], NoResponse.iloc[:,1])),` If I omit the last `,` the `NoResponse` variable doesn't get saved as `JSON` array, but if I include the comma, it does. Could you please let me know why is that.